# Getting garbage value while reading packet length from TCP

Tags: go, tcp, byte

#### Problem

I am sending packet using tcp, with first 8 byte as long which
contains the actual packet length while receiving it, after some point
it gets wrong packet length which causes the following error "slice
out of range" because the packet length that is received is way bigger
but using TCP Dump I can see it is receiving the correct packet size.

#### Client TCP Code

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net"
        "ByteBuffer"
        "log"
        "sync"
)

func main() {

        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.90.116:8300")

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }
        
        byteBuffer := ByteBuffer.Buffer{
                Endian:"big",
        }

        msg := "Hello World"

        totalByteLen := len(msg)  

        byteBuffer.PutLong(totalByteLen)

        byteBuffer.Put([]byte(msg))

        log.Println(byteBuffer.Array())

        for i:=0;i<1000000000000;i++{

              go write(conn, byteBuffer.Array()) 
        }
}

var lck = &sync.Mutex{}

func write(conn net.Conn, data []byte){

    lck.Lock()
    _, err := conn.Write(data)
    lck.Unlock()

    if err != nil{

        return
    }
}
```

#### Server TCP Code

```
func HandleRequest(conn net.Conn){

    defer conn.Close()

    for {

        // creating a 8 byte buffer array

        sizeBuf := make([]byte, 8)

        // reading from tcp sockets

        _, err := conn.Read(sizeBuf)

        // converting the packet size to int64

        packetSize := int64(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(sizeBuf))

        log.Println(packetSize)

        if packetSize < 0 {

            continue
        }

        // reading more bytes from tcp pipe of packetSize length

        /*

            Here it catches error as the packet size is incorrect but it throws error after receiving aroung 4-5K messages.
        */

        completePacket := make([]byte, packetSize)

        _, err = conn.Read(completePacket)

        // checking error type

        if err == io.EOF{

            break

        }

        if err != nil{

            break

        }

        fmt.Println(completePacket)

    }
}
```

Comment: `_, err := conn.Read(sizeBuf)` may put 1 to `len(sizeBuf)` bytes into `sizeBuf` and return. Please read the docs on `io.Reader`. Looks like you want `io.ReadFull`.

Comment: using io.ReadFull also facing the same issue, it works for random packets but suddenly gets the wrong packet and after that exception of slice is thrown

panic: runtime error: makeslice: len out of range

Comment: for extra checking : check that the number of bytes read from `conn` matches the amount you expect : `n , err := conn.Read(sizeBuf); if n != packetSize { log.Println("short read :", n, packetSize); break }`

Comment: likewise : check the written count on the client's side

Comment: If I break then the client socket will disconnect in every few seconds I am seen if I put a delay of 10ms then this issue does not occur but if the writes are very fast around 60mb/s then this issue occurs. Please suggest I am trying for past 2 days used bufio, TCP configs like linger, everything still no clue

Comment: Thanks, got the solution I guess using io.ReadAtleast solved the issue. testing multiple times to confirm